# How to combine two regular expressions by using AND and NOT operators

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions X and Y. I want to combine them as "X AND NOT Y"

X:`[a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ ,.'-]` (Some alphabetic and extra chars)

Y: `/\A\s*\z/` (White space)

I am not trying to completely avoid white space (like "JohnDoe"). I am trying to avoid inputs by only white space (like this: `"    "` So "John Doe" would be allowed).

Comment: You can omit the space from the character class, and prepend it while repeating it in a group `^[a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ,.'-]+(?: [a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ,.'-]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/hJP012/1 or use `\s+` instead of a single space.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this works thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the space from the initial character class, and repeat matching that same character class zero or more times in a non capturing group `(?: [a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ,.'-]+)*` with a space prepended

If you want to match 1 or more whitspace chars you could use `\s+`

```
\A[a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ,.'-]+(?: [a-zA-ZığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ,.'-]+)*\z
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Y7qT0/1)